# I do not see my subordinates' work - how do I manage them?

Tags: management

I work at a small creative company as a Producer. Until very recently, there was no hierarchy. Everyone reported directly to the owner/CEO.

Recently, he's (CEO) developed a hierarchy with various "departments". With the artists, it's easy for the heads of the departments to oversee their subordinates because they review all of the artists' work before having a producer send it to the clients. However, my position is primarily account management/line producing. I work directly with the clients, as do my subordinates. Right now we don't have a good system in place for me to review their work other than our daily status meetings. Those are essentially honor system since I have no way to truly know if they are doing their work in a timely manner. So, the only time I am aware of my subordinates not working effectively is when one of the sales reps and/or artists tells me that they are not responding to emails, saving assets, etc.

How can I effectively manage them if our current work process doesn't support me reviewing everything they do? I don't want to micro manage.

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever heard of SCRUM? It's a technique for managing teams of developers but I think it might apply to your case very well.

For example, you could set up weekly iterations where each component of the team takes on a self-contained amount of work, which at the end of the iteration it's either *done* or *not done*.

The trick is in defining what is "done" for you, but that's context-specific and it relates to your domain (graphics?).

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29) might be the best place to start, and it's very well done.

Comment: +1.  Video/Media production is *VERY* similar to software development (I've worked for years in both).  Video/Media production is just on much quicker timetables.  SCRUM is a very effective methodology (IMO) for either environment.

Comment: Thank you! I have not heard of this method so I will research it. The other problem I'm facing is that my boss (the owner/CEO) doesn't feel that we Producers/Project Managers need training on both management and on the software/programs we use (hence me never having heard of SCRUM). He's hired people with no experience and expects them to completely immerse themselves in their projects. If they don't understand what's going on, then the burden falls on my shoulders.

Comment: @user18392 the good thing about SCRUM is that you can teach it yourself in a few hours over a weekend. This PDF really changed the way I see teamwork: http://www.scrumprimer.com/

Comment: ps I really hope this will make your team's life better - in the end, they are the most important asset. If you quit tomorrow, things will continue to move forward. If they all quit tomorrow, on the other hand...

Comment: @user18392 - good link!  SCRUM - A day to learn, a lifetime to master.  Of course, the same can be said of Project Management in general.

Comment: @WesleyLong, I  have been reviewing SCRUM this afternoon and I am not sure if it's the right solution. I don't think the types of projects we work on (CGI, print, video) lend themselves very well to SCRUM. It would take me convincing my boss, all of our clients, and all of our artists, to shift the way we handle our work just to try it out - if it didn't work, I might lose my job. Any advice or other tips?

Comment: I first implemented without telling my boss - he only cared whether the work was done or not. At successful delivery, he believed what I did was right - but I never missed one of his requests (GANTTs, etc.). You'll have to adapt SCRUM to your specific environment.